# How is the Gastner-Newman equation implemented to create value-by-area cartograms?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, density, linear-algebra, differential-equations, diffusion

There is a [paper](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/papers/geocomp.pdf) called "Density-equalizing map projections: Diffusion-based algorithm and applications" by Michael T. Gastner and M. E. J. Newman, which explains their algorithm (which is based in diffusion equations) for generating value-by-area cartograms.

While it explains the theoretical side of the mathematics involved with their algorithm, it doesn't explain how they actually implemented it. I tried to piece it together by looking at the source code from [cart](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/cart/), but I don't have the programming knowledge (it's written in c, which I don't know) required to understand it.

If anyone has at least a decent understanding of it and can explain the steps needed to create a cartogram using their algorithm, that would be greatly appreciated. Otherwise, if you have other helpful resources on the topic, those would be good too.

Comment: This seems like a fairly broad request, which may not be feasible here. The best one could suggest would be diagram the program (e.g., [see this site](https://www.draw.io/)) and work from there. If you're familiar with any procedural language, you should be able to figure out the basics of C pretty quickly.

Comment: Aside from APL (and perhaps Lisp and various derivatives, one could argue on Perl), almost all programming languages look pretty much the same. But I'm not seeing a physics question here.

Comment: It's a physics question because the cartogram-generating method involves treating your population like a fluid and using various diffusion equations to describe the action of that population as it moves to equilibrium.